# Codeigniter controller in subdirectory not working in virtual host

Tags: apache, codeigniter, virtualhost, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I need help with CodeIgniter -- trying to it to work in virtual host envirnoment in Ampps.

I have been following the following tutorial:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/basecamp-style-subdomains-with-codeigniter/

I am trying to have two installations of CodeIgniter running in two directories:
/students and 
/teachers

```
www.test.com -> goes to /teachers directory

www.user1.test.com -> goes to /students directory
```

I have the above working on my local machine.  The different URL's take me to the correct directory.  CI works. Problem arises when I try to access controller using redirect.

if I try to `redirect('error')` I get:

user2.test.com/user2.test.com/error

Also get an "internal server error"

if I type in

user2.test.com/error

I get an "internal server error"

if I type in

user2.test.com/index.php/error

I get desired result

It works if I try to load view directly in

```
$this->load->view('error')
```

I think I need help with the urls and paths.   Any guidance most gratefully received.

---

Nothing particularly enlightening in CI log files

In Apache logs I find:
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Things I have changed:

---

htaccess in root - changed rewrite base.  Also takes out index.php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /students/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

 ErrorDocument 404 index.php

</IfModule>
```

---

**application/config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

As per tutorial.  Needs to be dynamic.

---

**my Apache hppd-vhosts.conf file**

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/Ampps/www/teachers"
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias test.com

    <Directory "C:/Program Files/Ampps/www/teachers">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/Ampps/www/students"
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias *.test.com

    <Directory "C:/Program Files/Ampps/www/students">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

---

index.php in root

kept as is.  Things got worse when I tried to change these

```
$system_path = 'system';
$application_folder = 'application';
```

Answer (score 0):

what about your host file? your host file should be `127.0.0.1 test.com` and first try to disable the student sub domain and see if it dose work. Its look like your both `ServerName test.com` is same try to change the other one with `student.com` and see whats happen most probably both are conflicting